# Deleting an image when deleting an item using multer

Tags: express, multer

Ok so I am using multer to upload an image of an item that a user submits.  However when the user deletes the item the image file is still on the server.
I have been trying to figure this out and I am not sure if its the way findByIdAndRemove() is deleting the user item before I am making the call to remove the image or what but I am getting the error saying that it cant find the file name of undefined. I am using a promise thinking it would allow me to do this but I am not sure of where else to go.  I am new at this and learning as I go. Here is my delete route:

```
router.delete("/item/:id", middleware.isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
  Promise.all([
    (Item.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id),
    fs.unlinkSync("./public/uploads/" + req.item.image))
  ])
    .then(() => {
      return res.render("products");
    })
    .catch(err => {
      return console.log("err", err.stack);
    });
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: where is the `image` param ? you are only binding the `id` in the request

Comment: Sorry, I was playing around with different things trying to test the errors until I could figure something out.  I changed the code to what it was when I first started.  I thought it should have been req.item.image but that doesnt work as well.  I know req.param.id is tied to the url for deleting the item but how would I get the image from that as well?

Comment: depends how you are saving it on the filesystem. if you are saving the image with filename = `req.params.id` just use that in the `unlinkSync` instead of `req.item.image`.

Comment: I'm saving it as req.file.filename and when I use it to show on the browser it call it with item.image which is why I assumed I would use item.image when trying to delete it

Comment: `if (typeof req.file !== undefined) {
        item.image = "/uploads/" + req.file.filename;
      } else {
        item.image = "/uploads/no-img.png";
      }`

Comment: that's how I am saving it ... code looks funny in a comment but that's it